# Field level validation - get name of the currently validated field

Tags: redux-form

I would like to get name of currently validated field (per-field sync validation - the one passed as `validate` prop to `Field`). Is it possible with redux form 7.0.3?

Comment: So far bad luck, https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/639d45edf57f99d2d55d49d0b063c00dcf5198bb/src/generateValidator.js#L17

Comment: Created an issue https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3350